# Electric hot water heater, no hot water after main break in city

Tags: water-heater

Electric hot water heater is not working after a nearby city water main break. Switched circuit breaker off and on and also hit reset on the heater, but still nothing. Water comes out of hot faucets, but is cold.(it has been 18 hours)

Comment: When you say "reset on the heater", do you mean the red button on the temperature control under the cover of the water heater? For some water heaters (usually larger tanks), there are two resets. One on each thermostat.

Comment: Any chance some water was removed from the tank.  Heating electrodes tend to burn out if not covered with water(slight chance).  Hopefully first comment is right.

Comment: Was the heater turned off while the city water supply was out, or was it left on for the duration?

Comment: Used red button under temperature control to reset. We didn't turn off water heater during outage...

Comment: I'm with @crip659 here.  A hot water heater's element will burn out in seconds if the water level drops enough to expose it.  In many cases when water pressure is lost the hot water tank can be siphoned out.  Check the resistance of the elements WITH THE POWER OFF AT THE BREAKER and see if it's an open circuit.

Comment: @crip659 move on down to the answer box and write that up.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  think it more of question/possible cause than an answer.  jwh20 is closer to being an answer.

Comment: If you have a voltmeter you can also (carefully) check to see if there's power to the elements.